# Why does Bifur have an axe in his head?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

I recently purchased a book called "The Hobbit : An Unexpected Journey Almanac 2013". In the book it shows Bifur the Dwarf having the remains of an orc axe in his head.

The book states, "Unable to talk, Bifur grunts and uses hand signals to communicate."

Why, when there is nothing mentioned of this in the book, would they add this to the movie?

[image]

Comment: Not watching this movie would probably be the best thing, I'm losing my temper with all these changes.

Comment: The worst part is: The world is supposed to end before we get to see parts two and three. We may be busy fighting zombies before Jackson gets a chance to tell us about ol' Bifur's excederin moment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can confirm that Bifur did not have an axe in his head in the book, and could speak. (He must have had about three lines of dialogue.)

Here is a passage from an [interview](http://www.theonering.net/torwp/2008/10/20/30314-del-toro-interview-part-2-this-is-the-hardest-movie-i%e2%80%99ll-probably-ever-do) of Guillermo del Toro, which does not mention Bifur but gives what is probably the motivation for his pecularity.

> (…) officially you have a story of all of them, and not treat them as secondary characters. (…) So if all thirteen look kind of alike, and all thirteen – or worse even, if they all look too much unlike each other, you know, so you can almost differentiate them with tag, then that’s almost worse. So you have to strike a real balance so that when that group comes in those are the ‘Seven Samurai’ and you know by the way they interact with each other that he was chosen because he keeps vigil, he’s in command, this one is loyal, these two are fighting all the
>   time but they’re willing to die for each other, blah, blah, blah (…)

In the book, the dwarves are differentiated by a few actions and bits of dialogue, which can't all be shown in a movie. An axe in the head and a speech impediment are good visual ways to set off a character. Mind you, in the book, Bifur and Bofur are pretty much indistinguishable, and usually part of a trio with Bombur (who is distinguished as being always picked last).

Apparently, the information that Bifur could only speak in Khuzdûl due to his injury was [leaked at ComicCon 2012](http://www.elendilion.pl/2012/07/13/g-i-p-report-dwalins-runes-orkrist-thranduil-and-wargs/). The *Almanac* is presumably more canonical that this rumor/leak.

Comment: Khuzdûl in the Hobbit, really? All these changes to are giving me a headache, I'm going to lay down.

Comment: @Secko Yeah, I blame the 1951 retcon.

Comment: Also, I heard the rumor they didn't use real Dwarves from Middle Earth in the movie. They used human actors with makeup!

Answer (score 5):

Allegedly Bifur only speaks in [Khuzdul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khuzdul) as a result of his injury (rather than the grunts and hand signals mentioned).  It could be a way to boost the presence of this created language, but most likely it is a combination of providing a way to tell the dwarves apart, showing how tough they are, and a "joke".  As far as I could find, there hasn't been a Word of God entry on the axe yet explaining exactly why brain damage is funny.